# IntroJS, Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an IntroJS demo that works fine in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zmtwzoj/8/).

When I merge it with my app, the button "Click me to test IntroJS" returns:
    `Uncaught ReferenceError: intro is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

- I checked the correct IntroJS css and JS libraries are loaded through the codepen CDN.
- I checked the spelling of the function. A test alert button triggers correctly..
- I tried `<body>` and other JSfiddle wrappers in the Codepen HTML head section. I've moved snippets from Codepen to JSfiddle before, and am aware of the usual errors.

I think it's a scope issue, but I'm not sure what to do next.

The JS is here, at line 381

```
  intro = introJs();
     intro.setOptions({
    'showStepNumbers': false
  });
  intro.start();

function testAlert() {
  alert("alert");
};
```

The button is here:

```
 <button onclick="intro.start();">Click me to Test IntroJS</button>
```

The [full app is here](https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/mRgWLg), buttons are halfway down:

Comment: the codepen works here: http://codepen.io/mayank_shubham/pen/pRBPjr

Comment: I can get it working OK as a standalone codepen as well, Shubham, but when I merge the code with my larger app, the buttons no longer work. https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/mRgWLg

Comment: when you call `intro.start()` from the inline event handler, you have to make sure the `intro` object is defined or exposed into the global scope (not wrapped into a DOMContentLoaded callback for instance). Can you show where is your `intro` object (and `start` function plus related code) is defined in your real app?

Comment: I don't think I defined it correctly, but I already have an answer. I need to do some reading on DOMContentLoaded, Global Scope and defining functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/mRgWLg) is that there is a JavaScript error at line 355:

```js
setText(playButton, "Play");
```

The variable *playButton* has not been defined.  This is preventing the rest of the JavaScript from working.  Once I commented out all references to *playButton*, the intro.js code executed as expected.

Comment: You have got really keen eyes, :)

Comment: Thanks clarmond, that works. I saw that playButton error come up in the console, but thought I could just leave it. I'll have to remember that mistakes in one area of a Javascript program can cause weird errors in a different part of the script. Lesson learned. Cheers.